# Can any IDE (eg PHPStorm, VS Code) correctly show functions added via require get_template_directory() string results?

Tags: theme-development, ide

I would simply like to do some WordPress theme development using statements like

```php
        require get_template_directory() . '/functions/base.php';
```

in my functions.php file. It seems IDEs do not know what to make of this function result and therefore do not map out [theme root]/functions/base.php as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In the process of looking this up I determined the correct answer is to use the full local path in my dev environment, and add a comment in the code like

```php
/** @define "get_template_directory()" "/home/myuser/mywpproject/wp-content/themes/mytheme" */
```

And this works for the subsequent references in that file in JetBrains IDE / PHPStorm immediately. Thanks to [here](https://validwebs.com/337/code-completion-in-phpstorm-with-wordpress/) by Jeff Behnke. I have not checked this on other IDEs. As this is a comment I believe it should not affect server side execution.